# Scrolling in a single div causes overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a `position:fixed` div with `overflow: auto;` as a transparent div in the back of some pop up.

The problem is when I scroll to see this pop up bottom or top, this overlap appears.

How could I keep using this div as a background with the ability to scroll without this overlapping?

[image: a transparent bg, and the pop up in the front]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="popup_screen_bg">
      <div class="popup_screen">
      <!-- update partner "form" -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup_screen_bg{
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url('popup_transparent.png');
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.popup_screen{
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80%;
  min-height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

**Note**: This problem appears only in Chrome.

Comment: Can you please show a jsfiddle so that we can get an idea of your page structure? Or at least type in some HTML.

Comment: I'm not unable to recreate the problem using the code above. I'll just post a picture in the answers and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is my test image]. You can see that it is scrolled down in google chrome, and there is no overlap. Maybe there's another reason? Or maybe it's just a glitch, since you said it is working on all other browsers. If you also look in the right, there are your styles, and your div is at the top of the interior of `<body>`.